# Change background color when UIAlertViewController row is pressed down

Tags: ios, swift, select, uialertcontroller

When a user holds down on an UIAlertController row, it naturally changes to a grey color on the iPad but I would like to make that another color. How can I do that?

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler:  { action in

        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler:  { action in
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!, completionHandler: nil)
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is what the iPhone does when you hold down a row. I want to change that background color.
[image: This is what the iPhone does when you hold down a row. I want to change that background color.]

Comment: did you try alert.view.tintColor = .yellow?

Comment: What do you mean by UIAlertController row?

Comment: try the: view.backgroundColor = .green

Comment: I guess the expected output is that when the 'Settings' in the alert view is pressed then the background colour of the 'Settings' button should be changed by code and should not be grey. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I have updated the description and added an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not.

> **Important**
>
> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

Source : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller